# Why does this not work for Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block

The following code doesn't work with Ruby 1.9.2:

```
def side_box(title, &block)
  render :layout => 'layouts/side_box', :locals => {:title => title} do 
    &block
  end
end
```

I am getting an error:

> syntax error, unexpected tAMPER
>         &block

What has changed (since 1.8.7) for this not to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def side_box(title, &block)
  render :layout => 'layouts/side_box', :locals => {:title => title} do 
    yield
  end
end
```

or

```
def side_box(title, &block)
  render :layout => 'layouts/side_box', :locals => {:title => title} do 
    block.call
  end
end
```

It works in Ruby 1.9 and 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 1.8.7 installed at the moment, but I'm pretty sure that this is illegal in 1.8.7, as well. The unary prefix `&` operator is only legal in parameter lists and argument lists.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Simone's answer, in case your block takes arguments (arg1, arg2), the correct syntax (in both 1.8 and 1.9) would be

```
def side_box(title, &block)
  render :layout => 'layouts/side_box', :locals => {:title => title} do 
    yield(arg1, arg2)
  end
end
```

or

```
def side_box(title, &block)
  render :layout => 'layouts/side_box', :locals => {:title => title} do 
    block.call(arg1, arg2)
  end
end
```

Comment: if you don't catch the &block in your second option, that option should be the fastest

Answer (score 0):

i didn't know, that this works in 1.8.7, the correct syntax should be

```
block.call
```

or

```
block[]
```

or

```
render :layout => 'layouts/side_box', :locals => {:title => title}, &block
```